# What is the best way to store URLs in Database to prevent Injection

Tags: php, database, encryption, code-injection

A user on my website can submit multiple links under their profile, what is the best way to ensure and protect against any injections. is `mysql_escape_string()` good enough?

Comment: *"is mysql_escape_string() good enough?"* - and I'll tell you why *in a minute...*

Comment: ...right here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string read that. A: Use a prepared statement.

Comment: What else could I use with that to ensure the best security?

Comment: I edited my 2nd comment to answer your question (even before you asked) *lol*

Comment: im using laravel is there a way to go around it in that?

Comment: you will need to consult their documentation. I believe it uses different methods and is out of the scope of the original question.